# Custom mapping for ex command -> still show typing in ex console

Tags: key-bindings, split

After I do a `:sp` or `:vsp` I find myself always turning off wrapping in the resulting window.

My first attempt at automating this action looks like this (for the vertical situation):

```
function! VerticalSplit()
  vsplit
  setlocal nowrap
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> :vsp :call VerticalSplit()<CR>
```

This seems to work, but a negative is that when I type `:vsp` it doesn't show my typing in the :ex console at the bottom of the screen. This becomes more noticeable when typing other commands such as `:vimgrep`.

Is there a way to still show my typing in the ex window, or perhaps a better approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: perhaps `:cabbrev` would be better for your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `:cabbrev` you can achieve what you want so Christian Brabandt has
made a great suggestion. Now you have two different approaches, on one hand
you could try Christian's suggestion and type in:

```
:cabbrev vsp vsplit <bar> set nowrap
:cabbrev sp split <bar> set nowrap
```

or, on the other hand, you could map <kbd>Enter</kbd> in command mode, check if you typed in either `sp` or `vsp` and if so set `nowrap` as follows:

```
function! WrapIfSplit()
   let cmdline = getcmdline()
   if cmdline == "vsp"
      return "\<C-U>vsplit \<bar> set nowrap\<CR>" 
   elseif cmdline == "sp"
      return "\<C-U>split \<bar> set nowrap\<CR>" 
   endif
   return "\<CR>"
endfunction

cnoremap <expr><silent> <CR> WrapIfSplit()
```